# "Hacerse" vs "volverse" with professions

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos

Are both the following sentences usual? Do they mean the same or does the first one imply a great effort? Example:

> - Él se hizo doctor.
> - Él se volvió doctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Those sentences are not usual. Professions involving a course of study will not take verbs like "hacerse" or "volverse". The usual verbs are "llegar a ser" or "recibirse/graduarse de/como":

- Después de varios años, llegó a ser doctor / se recibió de doctor / se graduó como doctor.

Occasionaly, "convertirse" can be used. This will suggest a process, a transformation, perhaps similar to "llegar a ser":

- Después de varios años, se convirtió en doctor.

"Hacerse" can be used to indicate a secondary or auxiliary process, not dependent on education but on experience:

- Después de un tiempo, se hizo médico de frontera.

"Volverse" will only be used with adjectives or with nouns denoting a quality:

- Con el tiempo, se volvió un médico famoso / un héroe de la medicina.

Comment: I found an exception!  *Y Dios se hizo hombre.*

Comment: @aparente001 "hombre" is not a profession.

Comment: Correct!  I'm not disagreeing with your answer.  I just felt a tiny satisfaction finding *something* of the form *Se hizo [alguien]*.

Comment: @Gustavson Could volverse be used to describe a situation where a person returned to being a doctor after a period of time spent doing some other job?

Comment: @Traveller Well, it could, but it would be very unusual to refer to a person ceasing to be a doctor and then becoming a doctor again. Being a doctor is a permanent profession, not just a job.

Comment: I forget the name, but there was some famous musician (violinist maybe) who took ten years off concertizing to practice medicine and then returned to music.

Comment: @Traveller - In many cases you'd want to choose *volver* instead of *volverse*, e.g. *Fulano volvió a practicar la medicina cuando su hijo cumplió tres años.*  Maybe this has to do with wanting to avoid the association with *volverse el estómago*.

Comment: somewat funny, the usage of "hacerse hombre", and "volverse gay" (or  "marica" and synonymous)

Comment: Just a note: "recibirse" is not used in Spain with that meaning.